# How to view width of a path's stroke in millimeters in Illustrator CS6?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

How can I view the width of a path's stroke in millimeters ? I can see the width and height values (see screenshot) in the info bar but these measure the width and height of the whole circle shape. I want to know the width of the stroke in mm. The path is expanded from a type object.

Illustrator version is CS6 Mac

[image: path selection screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just invoke MEASURE tool [image]

and in info window you can see the measures results continuously while you are clicked-and-dragging over the shape in question.

some [add info](http://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/rulers-grids-guides-crop-marks.html#measure_the_distance_between_objects) via adobe (there are a lot of measure tool tutes in youtube as well)

[image]

Comment: Thanks but that shows the dimensions of the whole shape, not the stroke

Comment: you're wrong, TRY it - click-and-drag over the stroke

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yh4BocYnu6E - expanded here

Comment: I did try it and then I realised you meant click and drag which you didn't put in your answer. Suggest you edit the answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: added, glad it helped